# Driver is not executable error in Jenkins but its running in Local Machine (MacBook)

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins

[image: jenkins server][image]

I am working on MacBook. Our Jenkins server is running in linux server when I running tests via testing.xml file all test classes are running but when I run Jenkins build its not getting run Error is saying driver is not executable

I have created maven project in Jenkins and give repo url of this project from bitbucket

anyone help me to sort out this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You should use ChromeDriver for Linux: [Downloads - WebDriver for Chrome](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

and then make the ChromeDriver executable using

```
chmod 750 chromedriver
```

or

```
chmod 777 chromedriver
```

For more see: [What Does chmod 777 Mean](https://linuxize.com/post/what-does-chmod-777-mean/#:%7E:text=If%20you%20are%20managing%20a,do%20anything%20with%20those%20files).

Comment: I did this too not working

Comment: are you using chromedriver for linux : https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/87.0.4280.20/chromedriver_linux64.zip

Comment: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Yes I am using chrome driver linux

Comment: please add your code also , how you are starting  chrome driver